# Reduce size of headless puppeteer screenshot

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I'm using a lambda function to launch puppeteer with headless chrome. I'm able to take a picture and save it to an s3 bucket, but the image is way too big. I was originally setting the viewport to default, but the image was still coming out as 1520 X 1520.

Here is my current code to launch the headless browser and take the screenshot.

```
const browser = await chromium.puppeteer.launch({
  executablePath: await chromium.executablePath,
  headless: chromium.headless,
  args: chromium.args,
  defaultViewport: { width: 800, height: 600, deviceScaleFactor: 2 },
  ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
});
    
const body = isJson(event.data ? event.data : event.body);
    
const timeStamp = Date.now();
const HandleBars = require("handlebars");
const bucketForTemplates = {
  Bucket: templateBucket,
  Key: `${body.template}.hbs`,
};

const file = await s3.getObject(bucketForTemplates).promise();

const template = HandleBars.compile(file.Body.toString());
const renderedPage = template(body);

const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.setViewport({ deviceScaleFactor: 2 });
await page.setContent(renderedPage);

//wait for page to load
await page.waitForSelector("#image");
const image = await page.$("#image");

const box = await image.boundingBox();
const x = box["x"];
const y = box["y"];
const w = box["width"];
const h = box["height"];

const buffer = await page.screenshot({
  type: "jpeg",
  clip: { x: x, y: y, width: w, height: h },
});
    
await page.close();
await browser.close();
//save image to s3.
```

The div I am taking a picture of has a set width of 760px and height of 760px but the screenshot is 1520 X 1520.

How do I reduce the size of the image to not be so big?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You launch puppeteer with `deviceScaleFactor: 2` viewport setting:

```
const browser = await chromium.puppeteer.launch({
  defaultViewport: { width: 800, height: 600, deviceScaleFactor: 2 }, // <----
});
```

[According to docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#puppeteerlaunchoptions), it "can be thought of as DPR", or [device pixel ratio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio), thus enlarging resolution by 2.

The default for this setting is `1`, which is what you'd like to use to get the screenshot of a correct size.

Comment: I spent four hours on this issue. Thank you!

Comment: An issue I had with this is that the quality is in fact quite a bit better if you use a higher `deviceScaleFactor` and then use some other library to down-size it.

Comment: @onassar Which library do you recommend to downsize it?

Comment: I used Sharp :)